# How can put 0 when is null in Angular 6 without using pipes or methods

Tags: angular

Is there a directive or something for validate if is null without using methods or pipes?

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
   <td>{{ item.nombre }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `||` operator.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index" >
   <td>{{ item.nombre || 0 }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to modify your list in your TS code:
    Something like this:

```
  list.foreach(element =>{
   elemnt.nombre = element.nombre ? element.nombre : 0;
  });
```

This way you have more control over your data.
Or if you simply are trying to modify a value to display, then you can use abney317's answer.

Give it a try.

Comment: did this answer helped you?